# Create invite to every server bot is in

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Currently, I want to create an invite for every server my bot is in. I've looked far and wide but there has been no solution for me that has worked, unfortunately.

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Client({ intents: [] });

client.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`Bot ${client.user.username} is ready`);
    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
        let channel = guild.channels.cache.first();
        let invite = channel.createInvite();
        console.log(invite.code);
    });
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

This is my code and the error I get is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createInvite')
```

which I can't understand. I feel like there is a simple solution but I am yet to find it. Thanks in advance.

Discord.js version: 14.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
  let channels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type === ChannelType.GuildText);
  guild.invites.create(channels.first().id).then(invite => console.log(invite.code))});
```

This should work, basically, we filter out all channels that the cache retrived so only text channels get saved, we then create an invite using GuildInviteManager's create and then log out the code.

(If this helped, please mark this answer as the solution.)